# Boton de instalacion PWA react

Tags: firebase, reactjs, pwa

quisiera saber si alguien sabe como agregar un boton en una pagina de inicio para instalar una PWA en React, es decir cuando se dirijan a mi pagina raiz que aparezca un boton que diga instalar y instale la PWA en el telefono o web, espero que se entienda, estoy usando como boilerplate el siguiente repositorio.

https://github.com/the-road-to-react-with-firebase/react-firebase-authentication

Comment: Quizás esto te sirva https://www.reactpwa.com/en/examples.html

Comment: Recuerda que para usar una app PWA necesitas el protocolo https y para que la instalación funcione

Answer (score 0):

Escuchando el evento 'beforeinstallprompt' de esta forma:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  setPrompActive(true);
});
```

Muestras un Promp para preguntarle al usuario si desea instalar tu PWA

No sería buena idea tener un botón permanente porque una vez instalada la PWA ya no será necesario. La referencia [aquí](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners)